# CakePHP: Can't get logged in user's group ID using Auth and Session

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.2

I am a beginner with CakePHP trying to build my first app.

I have the following login code:

```
function login() {
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {

        $result = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
            ),
            'fields' => 'Group.id'
        ));
        $groupId = $result['Group']['id'];
        $this->Session->write('Auth.Group.id', $groupId);
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in with Group ID ' . $groupId . '!', 'auth');
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I am setting the `Auth.Group.id` session variable, as well as the `auth flash`.

However, in my `app/views/layouts/default.ctp`, when I

```
<?php echo $session->flash() ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $session->flash('auth') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo 'ID=' . $session->read('Auth.Group.id'); ?>
```

I get nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: here is my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Acl', 'Session', 'Auth');

    function beforeFilter() {
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display','logout','login');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Containable Behavior in your Model? Regardless you should try changing your code per the following and see what happens...

```
function login() {
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {

    $result = $this->User->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
        ),
        'fields' => 'User.group_id' //CHANGE THIS
    ));
    $groupId = $result['User']['group_id']; //CHANGE THIS
    $this->Session->write('Auth.Group.id', $groupId);
    $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in with Group ID ' . $groupId . '!', 'auth');
}
```

}

Let me know if it displays a number, which should be your group_id for the user. If it does than you can use Containable Behavior to get Group Name if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have debug level set at 2? (in core.php).

The 2nd param of the setFlash is the name of an element used to render the message, in your case app/views/elements/auth.ctp. If it's missing it is normal that you don't get anything.

Try the following

In the controller:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in with Group ID ' . $groupId . '!'); // notice 2nd param removed
```

and in the layout:

```
<?php echo $session->flash() ?>
```

Comment: still nadda. edited post with AppController, maybe the problem lies there?